# Excel merging two rows into one

Tags: excel

May I know how to merge two data into one cell? 
For example:

A1 - 100100
A2 - 110000

into

A3 - 100100
            110000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate them as you normally would, and a line feed (`char(10)`) in the middle:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & B1
```

Make sure that "Wrap text" is set for cell A3.

Answer (score 2):

or alternately:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1; CHAR(10);A2)
```

you'll still need the Wrap text enabled.

good page to learn more about excel functionality like this

> http://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-string-concatenation.html